# How to check if data frame column value appears in all unique year in the data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['cst1', 'cst1', 'cst1','cst1','cst2','cst2','cst2','cst3','cst3','cst3','cst3'],'year':[2017,2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020,2017,2018,2019,2020]})

   type  year
0   cst1  2017
1   cst1  2018
2   cst1  2019
3   cst1  2020
4   cst2  2018
5   cst2  2019
6   cst2  2020
7   cst3  2017
8   cst3  2018
9   cst3  2019
10  cst3  2020
```

For above dataframe need to check with each type value if it is present in the all four years [2017,2018,2019,2020] need to label as 1, other wise 0.
ex: first type cst1 appeared in all 4 years so labeled as 1, cst2 appeared only in 3 years so labeled as 1.
Note: Ideally the contains only for four years i,e 2017 - 2020. Type and year combination will be unique.

desired output:

```
type  year label
0   cst1  2017     1
1   cst1  2018     1
2   cst1  2019     1
3   cst1  2020     1
4   cst2  2018     0
5   cst2  2019     0
6   cst2  2020     0
7   cst3  2017     1
8   cst3  2018     1
9   cst3  2019     1
10  cst3  2020     1
```

Comment: Would `cst4` be 1 or 0 if it had `[2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021]`?

Comment: Additional question would `cst4` be 1 or 0 if it had `[2017, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2020]`?

Comment: @HenryEcker Yes, good point! And let's also add `[2019,2017,2018,2020]` to our list... :)

Comment: @perl thanks for your response, data contains only four years which starts from 2017 - 2020. Type and year combination will be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess groupby/transform with nunique will do if all the years are in range 2017 -2020:

```
df['label'] = (df1.groupby('type').transform('nunique') == 4).astype(int)
```

Alternative:

```
df1['label'] = 0 
def test(x):
    return set(x.values) == {2017,2018,2019,2020}
df1.iloc[df1.groupby('type')['year'].filter(test).index , 2] = 1
```

Comment: It will be better to compare exact years rather than number of years as it will fail if there are 4 years but not required 4 years.

Answer (score 2):

- Make groups on the basis of **type** using `groupby()`
- Get tuple of years in each row based on group using `transform()`
- Compare those tuples with your required years. It will result **True/False** for each row.
- Convert boolean **(True/False)** to integer **(1/0)** using `astype('int')`

```
required = (2017,2018,2019,2020)
df1["label"] = (df1.groupby('type').transform(tuple)["year"] == required).astype('int')

print(df1)

    type    year    label
0   cst1    2017    1
1   cst1    2018    1
2   cst1    2019    1
3   cst1    2020    1
4   cst2    2018    0
5   cst2    2019    0
6   cst2    2020    0
7   cst3    2017    1
8   cst3    2018    1
9   cst3    2019    1
10  cst3    2020    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try:

1. a [groupby transform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-seriesgroupby-transform) to test if each group's years is a subset of the desired years.
2. Convert Booleans to 1s and 0s using `astype(int)`

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['cst1', 'cst1', 'cst1', 'cst1', 'cst2', 'cst2',
                             'cst2', 'cst3', 'cst3', 'cst3', 'cst3'],
                    'year': [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2017,
                             2018, 2019, 2020]})

years = {2017, 2018, 2019, 2020}

df1['label'] = (
    df1.groupby('type').year.transform(lambda x: years.issubset(x))
).astype(int)
print(df1)
```

`df1`:

```
    type  year  label
0   cst1  2017      1
1   cst1  2018      1
2   cst1  2019      1
3   cst1  2020      1
4   cst2  2018      0
5   cst2  2019      0
6   cst2  2020      0
7   cst3  2017      1
8   cst3  2018      1
9   cst3  2019      1
10  cst3  2020      1
```

---

*Note this will match any group that has *at least* the four years. So if a group includes entries from [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020] it will be matched.